# is there a way to watch multiple file types with vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to be able to watch for multiple file types. `**/*.spsrc` and `**/*.spinc`
do I have to watch for `**/*.*` instead and filter the extra notifications?

Answer (score 2):

No, this can be done with a single watcher. Relevant section from the [`GlobPattern`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#GlobPattern) docs:

> Glob patterns can have the following syntax:
>
> [....]
>
> - `{}` to group conditions (e.g. `**​/*.{ts,js}` matches all TypeScript and JavaScript files)

So for your example, that would look like this:

```ts
vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher("**/*.{spsrc,spinc}");
```